# Import routing and root sourcing

Tags: javascript, import

I have a project in javascript whose files I use to setup on root folder structure. However, since source file is where most of main files go, it becomes somewhat verbose to write `..` multiple times.

`import package from '../../utils/functions';`

Is there some convenient way to refer every import route without either single `./` or double `../` dot by some `package.json` configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some Alias like [npm alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) that can do it, changing "../../../" to something like "@root/yourFile", "@controller/yourFile"

Comment: IT SHOULD BE OFFICIAL!